# Expected value of a Pareto distribution between two values

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

Suppose that we have a Pareto distribution for $x \ge \theta$:

$$f(x;k;\theta)= \frac{k\theta^k}{x^{k+1}} $$

We can calculate $ E[X]$ with the following
$$ E[X] = \int_{\theta}^{\infty} \frac{k\theta^k}{x^k} dx = \frac{k\theta}{k-1} $$
provided $k>1$.

Now, what if we want to calculate the average value between two values $a$ and $b$.

We can do

$$
\int_a^b xf(x)dx = \int_a^b x \frac{k\theta^k}{x^{k+1}} dx = \frac{k\theta ^k}{1-k} \left[x^{-k+1}\right]_a^b
$$
$$
= \frac{k\theta ^k}{1-k} (b^{-k+1}-a^{-k+1})       
$$

Now, if b is infinite, we can fin the expected value. And let choose some values for a, intuitively, if a increases, the average value between a and b (infinite) should increase. Mabybe I am wrong, but then I don't know.

Now let's plot some values for a with r:

```
theta=3
k = 1.1

a= seq(3,10,0.1)

mm = - k * theta ^k/(1-k) * a ^(-k+1)

plot(a,mm)
```

we can see that `mm` decrease with the value of a.

[image]

Could you please help me to understand why, or there may be an error in the formulas.

Thank you

Comment: As you consider only the average value of $X$ over a limited interval, you must compute a weighted mean, i.e. 
$$
\mu_{[a,b]} = \frac{\int_a^b xf(x) \,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_a^b\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{k\theta^k}{1-k} \frac{b^{1-k}-a^{1-k}}{b-a}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at the truncated Pareto-distribution on an interval $(a,b), b>a>0$ (which means you cut off the part before $a$ and after $b$), you forgot to divide through the probability that $X$ actually falls into the intervall. Let $F(x;k;\theta)$ be the cdf of the Pareto distribution, then the pdf of the truncated Pareto distribution wrt the interval $(a,b)$ is given through
$$\frac{f(x,k,\theta)}{F(b,k,\theta)-F(a,k,\theta)}, \qquad x \in (a,b) $$
Moreover the corresponding expectation is
$$\int_a^bx\frac{f(x,k,\theta)}{F(b,k,\theta)-F(a,k,\theta)}dx $$
For $b,k,\theta$ fixed the latter expression increases as $a$ increases.